# error with array size

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to make a program that calculates the amount of prime numbers that don't exceed an integer using the sieve of Eratosthenes. While my program works fine (and fast) for small numbers, after a certain number (46337) I get a "command terminated by signal 11" error, which I suppose has to do with array size. I tried to use malloc() but I didn't get it quite right. What shall I do for big numbers (up to 5billion)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
signed long int x,i, j, prime = 0;
scanf("%ld", &x);
int num[x];
for(i=2; i<=x;i++){
  num[i]=1;
}
for(i=2; i<=x;i++){
  if(num[i] == 1){
    for(j=i*i; j<=x; j = j + i){
      num[j] = 0;
    }
    //printf("num[%d]\n", i);
    prime++;
  }
}
 printf("%ld", prime);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array indexes run from *zero* to size minus one.

Comment: 'for(i=2; i<=x;i++)'   bounds.......................

Comment: Oh... I was not fast enough.  I wasted time checking for strlen/sizeof(pointer) before checking the for loop indexes:(

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't think that's a problem since it works perfectly for  every number up to 46337

Comment: It is a problem; trust us. Your program behaviour is currently undefined. Meaning it might work, but, on the other hand it might not.

Comment: Think about what happens when you write out of bounds of the `num` array, where will the program write then?

Comment: Big numbers will work if you use a single bit instead of  a whole int for storing 0 or 1. Perhaps one of the few good uses for `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: Please indent consistently suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that allows many levels across the width of the page and is wide enough to be visible even when using variable width fonts.

Comment: When asking for the user to input something, always prompt the user so they know what to input.  Otherwise the user is looking at a blinking cursor and has no idea what is needed.

Comment: for readability, use a blank line around code blocks (if, else, for, while, do...while, etd)  only declare a single variable in a statement, only declare a single variable per line.  That greatly helps with readability/understandability of the code and makes documentation easy.

Comment: this line: `for(i=2; i<=x;i++)` and this line: `for(i=2; i<=x;i++)` and this line: `or(j=i*i; j<=x; j = j + i)` write beyond the end of the num[] array.  In C, an array index begins with 0 and ends with array lenght-1

Comment: after correcting the out of bounds problems, I ran the code with inputs as high as 900000 with no problems (I saw no reason to bother testing with larger values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array

```
int num[x];
```

is on the stack, where only small arrays can be accommodated. For large array size you'll have to allocate memory. You can save on memory bloat by using `char` type, because you only need a status.

```
char *num = malloc(x+1);              // allow for indexing by [x]
if(num == NULL) {
    // deal with allocation error
}

//... the sieve code

free(num);
```

I suggest also, you must check that `i*i` does not break the `int` limit by using

```
if(num[i] == 1){
    if (x / i >= i){                  // make sure i*i won't break
        for(j=i*i; j<=x; j = j + i){
            num[j] = 0;
        }    
    }    
}
```

Lastly, you want to go to 5 billion, which is outside the range of `uint32_t` (which `unsigned long int` is on my system) at 4.2 billion. If that will satisfy you, change the `int` definitions to `unsigned`, watching out that your loop controls don't wrap, that is, use `unsigned x = UINT_MAX - 1;`

If you don't have 5Gb memory available, use bit status as suggest by @BoPersson.

Comment: THANK YOU. the problem was with the i*i breaking the limit not with the array. job done :)

Comment: @PanagiotisPapantonakis perhaps a vote or "accept" from you please?

Comment: @PanagiotisPapantonakis thanks -  and don't forget you do need the `x+1` array size.

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks for errors, tested with values up to 5000000000, properly outputs the final count of number of primes, uses malloc so as to avoid overrunning the available stack space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int x,i, j;
    unsigned prime = 0;
    scanf("%lu", &x);

    char *num = malloc( x);
    if( NULL == num)
    {
        perror( "malloc failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    for(i=0; i<x;i++)
    {
      num[i]=1;
    }

    for(i=2; i<x;i++)
    {
      if(num[i] == 1)
      {
        for(j=i*i; j<x; j = j + i)
        {
          num[j] = 0;
        }
        //printf("num[%lu]\n", i);
        prime++;
      }
    }
     printf("%u\n", prime);
     return 0;
}
```